# How can I write a unit test with pagination in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to write unit tests for my project in django rest framwork but I can not compare my res.data with my serializer.data
This is my json for one object Brand :

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:8000/shops/tags/1/",
      "id": 1,
      "name": "PS4",
      "link": "https://www.playstation.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my unit test :

```py
BRANDS_URL = reverse('brands-list')
    def test_retrieve_brand_list(self):
        """Test retrieving a list of brands"""
        Brand.objects.create(name='Bestbuy', link='https://bestbuy.ca')
        Brand.objects.create(name='Amazon', link='https://amazon.ca')
        res = self.client.get(BRANDS_URL)

        brands = Brand.objects.all().order_by('-name')

        context = {'request': RequestFactory().get('/')}
        serializer = BrandsSerializer(brands, context=context, many=True)

        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(res.data, serializer.data)
```

My serializer :

```py
class BrandsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'name', 'link')
```

How I can add count, next, previous and results to my serializer.data ?
How I can have a serializer.data like res.data ?
I'm a little lost, I can not find a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
*self.assertEqual(res.data['results'], serializer.data)*
```

Hope this helps.